# Find the subgroups of H and the normalizer of H in $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have  a subgroup of $S_4$ defined by 
H={1,(1243),(1342),(12)(34),(14)(32),(13)(24),(14),(23)}.

I have to find the subgroups of H and the normalizer of H in $S_4$

The order of H is eight and I know that the order of the subgroup of H is a divisor of eight. 
{1} and H are te banal subgroups but the others subgroup?

Comment: Well, you must have heard of cyclic subgroups, which is a good place to start. There is no point in me doing all the work- if you think for yourself, you will learn more.

Comment: three subbgroups of order 2 : {1,(12)(34)},{1,(14)(32)},{1,(13)(24)}

Comment: one cyclic subgroup of order 4 :{1,(1243),(1342),(14)(32)}

Comment: Those are correct, but actually what I said was incorrect- there are two further subgroups of order $2$ as well ( both cyclic of course).

Comment: {1,(14)},{1,(23)} .Are these all the subgroups of H?

Comment: also {1,(12)(34),(14)(32),(13)(24)} and {1,(14),(23),(14)(23)}

Comment: and the normalizer of H in $S_4$?

Comment: You have found all the sub groups of $H$, yes. What are the possibilities for $|N_{G}(H)|$? Is $H \lhd S_{4}$?

Comment: to prove H is normal I write classes of laterals dx and sx?

Comment: I do not understand your notation. You need to check the definition of a normal subgroup, and see if it applies here.

Comment: i don't know how to prove H is a normal subgroup in $S_4$

Comment: The definition says  that $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $xHx^{-1} = H$ for all $x \in G$. This is the same as $xhx^{-1} \in H$ for all $x \in G$ and $h \in H$. Maybe you could read about when elements of $S_{n}$ are conjugate to each other if you have done it in class.

Comment: order of $S_4$ is 24 and order of H is 8 so I have 3 conjugated classes.And then?

Comment: I think you need to review your class notes and/or books.

Comment: H*1=1*H=H ; H*(12)={(12),(143),(234),(34),(1324),(1423),(124),(132)}  but (12)*H={(12),(243),....; so H is not normal in $S_4$?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: so $|N_G(H)|$ is null?

Comment: I hope you can see why $H$ should be a subgroup of $N_{G}(H)$ ( if not, think some more). By Lagrange's theorem, that severely restricts the possible values of $|N_{G}(H)|$. But now you know that $N_{G}(H)$ is not the whole of $S_{4}$, so you should be able to see what it is.

Comment: if H is normal $N_G(H)=G$?

Comment: You need to think about that yourself.

Comment: the order of H is a divisor of the order of $N_G(H)$ so I have two possibility: 8,16

Comment: But also $|N_{G}(H)|$ must divide $24$, as $N_{G}(H)$ is a subgroup of $S_{4}$, which has order $24$.

Comment: but |N_G(H)| isn't 24 because is not the whole $S_4$.So 8 or 16 are the possibility

Comment: Does 16 divide 24?

Comment: so the order is eight. How can i find the elements of the normalizer?

Comment: $H$ is a subgroup of $N_{G}(H)$. How many elements does $H$ have?

Comment: Order H is eight so $H=N_G(H)$?

Comment: There seems to be no other possibility.